# Database + Java Servlet: how to run database?

Tags: html, database, servlets, web

For a project, I am creating a small website that uses login functionality and has a database to store user info.

I'm wondering if it is possible to simply create a database, put it in a directory with all of my other website files, and then send that folder to someone so that when they open the folder, they will be able to use the website, and all of the login functionality.

I know how to run a postgres database on my localhost, but I don't understand how I can send the folder to someone else because they obviously wont have access to the database on my local host.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database must run on a server, it is not just a regular file which you read and write. If you want somebody else to access your database you can generate a script which will create the database from scratch and send that script. The receiver will run the script and will have the database created on his running instance of server.

The second option would be to connect directly to your server through internet. You must have a public IP (known by who connects) and the firewall configured appropriately.

Comment: If I do it the first way, and my servlets are using JDBC which requires me to specify a driver for Postgres, or MySQL or etc, does this mean that the only way it will work is if the person I send it to is using the same type of database system on their server that I specify for my driver?

Comment: Yes, it must be the same. For example if you dump your MySQL database, that script will run only on a MySQL server.